only to have an allergic reaction

He drank that special drink that had just come out to have an allergic reaction.


He drank that special drink that had just come out only to have an allergic reaction.

In the first sentence, is it at all possible that he didn't intend to have an allergic reaction?
In the second sentence, is it at all possible that he intended to have an allergic reaction?

The first: he did intend an allergic reaction (unlikely in real life); the second: he neither intended nor expected one.

Will you please either drop '… that had just come out…' or rephrase the exposition to show how it helps? Similarly, '… special …' and possibly even '…drink …'?
I see how this might seem pedantic, yet what but confusion do the example sentences add to 'He drank that to…'?
In the first sentence yes, it's quite possible he didn't intend to have a reaction?
In the second, yes, it's even more possible he intended to have a reaction?
In both cases that 'pedantic' clutter obscures too much.

Thank you all so much, and yes, Robbie, you are right, There is a lot of clutter. I was just trying to provide some 'context', but it backfired. Sorry. I think in your reply the two last question marks should be actually full stops, Is that correct?

There are two issues here: meaning and complexity.
As to meaning, the first sentence implies intention. However the second sentence is ambiguous. It may or may not imply intention. To see this, consider a simpler example:


He went to the library to see a friend.
He went to the library only to see a friend.
He went to the library, only to see a friend.


In sentence (1) his purpose was to meet his friend. In sentence (3) that was not his purpose, and the meeting was a coincidence. The comma is an important punctuation mark here, making the intended meaning clear. But in sentence (2) it's unclear. It could be the same as sentence (3), with a comma implied. But it could also mean that his sole purpose in going to the library was to meet his friend. Sentence (1) leaves open the possibility that there were other (unstated) reasons for his visit to the library.
Which points us to the other issue: complexity. My advice is to never write those kinds of sentences in the first place. In order to provide an answer I found it necessary to look at simpler patterns. Our general goal in writing English should be to communicate clearly. If you're not sure about possible ambiguity, then rewrite the sentence.

a. He drank that special drink that had just come out, because he wanted to have an allergic reaction.
b. He drank that special drink that had just come out, but had an unexpected allergic reaction.

Now there is no doubt what level of intention is implied in each sentence.

+1 'My advice is to never write those kinds of sentences in the first place.'
